# Unable to automate the Angularjs Click through Selenium driver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, phantomjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is there a possible way to automate the click event of angularjs button, which navigates to a new page in turn.

Something like following is what the original browser code is.

"data-ng-click="services.urls.openPageUrlWithId(plusPageId)"

I am able to get to the point where the click event comes into picture, but it is not getting navigated to a different screen.

Any solution to this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for end-to-end testing purposes?

If so, the angular team themselves maintain a fantastic tool called **protractor** https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/

It provides smart abstractions on top of WebDriverJS/Selenium to allow you to easily find elements by their angular bindings and click through as you have described.